# Execute Spacebar or Backspace with function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

this is my code in JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  event.code === 'Space';
})
```

I want to execute my keyboard with a function of javascript. Thank you for answering me

Comment: Are you asking to run JS when a key is pressed, or fake a keypress with JS? (Your code looks like the first option, your question sounds like the second)

Comment: Attach that DOM listener to your page, add `console.log(event)` and see what happens when you press one of those keys

Answer (score 1):

```
let element = document.querySelector('input');
element.onkeydown = e => alert(e.key);
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
'key': 'a'
}))
```

Comment: can you check my code i post it under your answer

Comment: Hey! can you please explain what you're trying to do and where it's going wrong ?